# Get user position between users

Tags: python

I have a database of users with marks.

I want to loop into marks and get user positions. Let's say `user1` marks are higher, the position would `1` and so on.

The output would be something like this:

```
user1 5121 1
user2 500  2
user3 400  3
```

I tried with:

```
sorted(range(len(user[marks])), key=lambda i: a[i], reverse=True)
```

But this only print out the highest to lowest.

My database model:

```
class user(db.Model):        
    id = db.Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = db.Column(String(250), nullable=False)
    marks = db.Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    position = db.Column(Integer, nullable=False)
```

Comment: You can try `pandas.DataFrame`, you can use that to sort your database easier

Comment: Please include column headings for your database, so we can easily determine which fields you are using for your method.  Additionally, when you state you want to get position of users please clarify what you mean.  If you don't want to print users in order, what exactly do you want to accomplish?

Comment: Can you say some more about your "database". If it's a traditional RDBMS then you can do this with appropriately constructed SQL

Answer (score 0):

If you can get you data in Pandas DataFrame then you can do something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "user": ['user1', 'user2', 'user3'],
    "marks": [5121, 400, 500]
})

# Sort dataframe by marks, and use index as rank
df.sort_values(['marks'], ascending=False, ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean you want to find the rank. Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "user": ['user1', 'user2', 'user3'],
    "marks": [5121, 400, 500]
})

df['rank'] = df['marks'].rank(method='dense', ascending=False).astype(int)

df = df.sort_values('rank', ignore_index=True)
```

Your output would look like this:

```
     user  marks  rank
0   user1   5121     1
1   user3    500     2
2   user2    400     3
```

`ignore_index=True` would reindex based on rank as well

Comment: thankyou @mank, i would also like to update user position on the database how can i get the rank for each user

Comment: You can add `df.set_index('rank')` to now index on the rank so the position in the pandas dataframe would be indexed by rank values. I am not sure what you mean by updating user position.

Comment: You can then add what Anurag mentioned earlier on rank to sort based on rank value

Answer (score 0):

You already achieved the sorted list of marks, highest to lowest, let's call it `ranks`. Just enumerate it and add 1.

```
[(i+1,e) for i,e in enumerate(ranks)]
```

Not sure why pandas is needed. Provide exact fields and formats for more detail.